# Parallelogram involving the incenter of a Right Triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> Let be $I$ the incenter of the triangle with the measure of $\angle A = 90$ degrees. If point $D$ lies on line $AB$ and $E$ lies on line $AC$ such that $BD \cong CE \cong BC $ and lines $BE$ and $CD$ intersect each other in $F$, then prove that $FEID$ is a parallelogram.

I know there's a few basic ways to prove a quadrilateral is a parallelogram, such as showing opposite sides are congruent or parallel. But I'm not too sure how to make use of all these conditions though. There seems to be a lot of different information and I'm not quite sure how to make use of all of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just prove by angle chasing that two pairs of opposite angles are equal in $FEID$ and thereafter it's a parallelogram.

It turns out that $\angle EFD=\angle EID=45^{\circ}$ and $\angle FEI=\angle FDI=135^{\circ}$.